# Files not seen in terminal

Tags: filesystem

Today I started experiencing a unique problem on my external drive.
The file manager pcmanfm is able to show all files. I am able to edit and save files from gedit or other such programs.

But when I try to access it from terminal, the files are not shown at all. This drive used to work well from terminal before today.

I tried to commit some changes in git repository via atom, which did not succeed on first go. On second go, I was able to commit it via atom.

All tutorials online seem to be about the reverse problem i.e. files visible on terminal but absent from file manager.

EDIT

```
$ ls -la /media/dhaval/Expansion\ Drive
total 8
drwxrwxrwx  2 dhaval dhaval 4096 May 17 09:23 .
drwxr-xr--+ 3 root   root   4096 May 17 09:50 ..
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us some more details. What are the file names? How are you trying to see them from the terminal? How is the drive mounted? What file system? What is the output of `ls -la /path/to/drive`?

Comment: Along with the request from @terdon, show the group membership of your user (grep username /etc/group). Did you manually mount this drive? I suspect you may be looking in the wrong directory for your files. If you are using a USB drive it's typically mounted in /media/username/somedir.

Comment: You should avoid spaces in file names. Do you mount the drive via `fstab`? Take a look at https://superuser.com/questions/527495/how-to-mount-partition-with-spaces-in-path

Comment: It seems that there was a folder created accidentally in the place where the external drive was trying to mount with the same name. Deleted the empty directory and then it mounted snd showed files as usual.

Comment: That is reproducible. You can add the explanation as an answer below to help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there was a folder created accidentally in the place where the external drive was trying to mount with the same name. Deleted the empty directory and then it mounted snd showed files as usual.